# Linux Kernel won't update to 2.35.25

Tags: kernel, updates

My recent linux kernel version is 2.35.24. Yesterday, there was an update which is 2.35.25 but after the update, my kernel version is still stuck at 2.35.24. Is there any option to get it to 2.35.25?

Comment: Did you reboot first? You didn't say.

Comment: i did a reboot , i did it everytime i update my kernel

Answer (score 2):

Did the update install?

There are lots of reasons why a kernel update would refuse to install, perhaps your machine is blacklisted because of known issues.

To find out what kernels you have installed, use this command:

```
ls /lib/modules/
```

To find out which one you're using, use this command:

```
uname -r
```

When you boot, you can press [Esc] to get the grub menu, what does the grub menu show. You can select any of the installed kernels from this list too. You can show this list while booted like so:

```
cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg | grep echo
```

If it's not there and it's not installed, attempt to install it from the command line:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-2.6.32-25-generic
```

If the version is installed, but not listed, then you might have a configuration issue, and you should be able to run this to fix it:

```
sudo update-grub2
```

Comment: it says it is already installed but when i type uname-r , it says im using 2.6.35.24 rather than the newest 2.6.35.25

Comment: See my further amendments to my answer above.

Comment: What options are available at the grub boot menu when you reboot ?

Answer (score 1):

There may be those that disagree, but, I have found that going into Synaptic, searching for Linux...

making sure the headers and image for the set you are wanting are installed (and have been installed in the correct order)

eg for the Kernel you want would have:

***headers ...***

headers for your bit config

image for your bit config

If all are not there, find a source and install all 3 in THIS ORDER

***the headers for all (the 'deb' would say all.deb)***

the headers for you bit configuration (32 or AMD64)

the image for your bit configuration (32 or AMD64)

update grub2

restart, checking to see which version you are running, at that time..

If running the correct version, and you don't want to go back...

You can simplify some of what is next with 'ailurus' but, basically, if nothing else,

Or:

Go back to synaptic and remove the other 'older' kernels.AFTER MAKING SURE YOU HAVE NEWER ONES RUNNING!!!

Briefly:

Re-install the newer kernel in the correct order.

Restart

Make sure all three of the newer kernel parts are up in Synaptic.

Update Grub2

Restart.

Check again to make sure the 'newer kernel' is up...

If you then want, get rid of older kernels through Synaptic or other package.