# Cannot update linux kernel from 2.6.38.3+ to 3.2.0

Tags: 11.10, kernel

Evervryone.

First, please forgive my bad english. And I'm using Google CR-48 and installed Ubuntu 11.10 in it.

Recently, I have updated Ubuntu which used command `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Also, I have installed VMware in it. Unfortunely, when I open it, it pops up a `Vmware Kernel Module Updater`.

After I searched, the kernel(?) is lost in `/usr/src/`. so I updated the kernel 3.2 which published recently directly. But I followed these web-site procedure below.

The website are below respectively.

- [Howto Compile and Install Linux Kernel 3.8 / 3.0 in Ubuntu 12.10, 12.04, 11.10, 11.04 and 10.04](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-compile-and-install-linux-kernel-3-0-in-ubuntu-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/)
- [How to Install Linux Kernel 3.9 raring in Ubuntu 13.04, 12.10, 12.04, 11.10, 11.04](http://www.howopensource.com/2011/08/how-to-install-linux-kernel-3-1-rc2-oneiric-in-ubuntu-11-04-10-10-and-10-04/)

After I followed these steps, and reboot the CR-48. It still fail and cannot update kernel to 3.2 when I used the command in terminal `uname -r` and it still shows me `2.6.38.3+`.

After I did some research, I found a module or kernel(?) (I don't know and I'm so sorry about that) in `/lib/modules/` and there is a folder called `2.6.38.3+`.

And I found a post [Linux Kernel won't update to 2.35.25](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23637/linux-kernel-wont-update-to-2-35-25) in here and I followed these steps, It's still cannot update the kernel.

So what should I do now? Thanks for everyone helping.

Answer (score 2):

I'm the person who asking this question. I found the answer which post the link below.

[I am running Ubuntu on my CR48 how do I install a new kernel?](http://www.reddit.com/r/CR48/comments/j3oeo/i_am_running_ubuntu_on_my_cr48_how_do_i_install_a/)

Or If you have another answer, please post it and discuss together. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the .deb files in ubuntu mainline. Downloaded and installed 3.2.4 without problems. However I cannot remove the old kernel. It just doesn't want to be removed.

BTW as far as usr/scr I found that in checking the files there. My new kernel placed files there.

Answer (score 0):

For being able to build the out-of-tree modules, you need the `linux-headers-$(uname -r)` package. Seeing the `+` on the end, I believe that your `2.6.38.3+` kernel is compiled yourself.

I recommend to build a `.deb` package which could then be installed with `dpkg` (and uninstalled as well):

```
make oldconfig
make INSTALL_MOD_STRIP=1 deb-pkg -j30
```

Change `30` to a number between *CPU cores + 1* (if you're CPU bound) and *twice CPU cores* (if you're I/O bound). `INSTALL_MOD_STRIP` yields smaller packages as it removes debugging information from the modules. This process will create four `.deb` files, namely `linux-firmware-image`, `linux-headers`, `linux-image` and `linux-libc-dev`. The most important here are the `linux-image-VERSION` and `linux-headers-VERSION` packages; the first contains the kernel image and modules, the second one headers which are needed to compile out-of-tree modules.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But stupid me. Would you mind tell me step by step? I'm still not clear. 

And, when I typed command `make oldconfig`, it shows me that **make: *** No rule to make target `oldconfig'. Stop.**

Comment: You need to run `make oldconfig` from the directory containing the kernel sources (i.e. the tar.bz2 file from http://kernel.org/). If you're not familiar with it, I recommend you to use the kernel from Ubuntu's repositories as you'll receive updates for them.

Comment: But `2.6.38.3+` in `/usr/src` is missed. Can I go to `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-030200-generic` to run `make oldconfig`?

Thanks again.

Comment: `2.6.38.3+` is a custom kernel, not something from the Ubuntu repositories. No, you can't jump in `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2...` as it contains headers only and not the source.

Comment: So what should I do now? I'm still not clear. Because there isn't `2.6.38.3+` in `/usr/src/`, then how can I `make oldconfig` in terminal?

Comment: Where did you get that kernel from?! Ubuntu 11.10 supplies with kernel 3.0 by default. If you want to use 3.2, use the link under "Latest Stable Kernel" at http://kernel.org/

Comment: Because My CR-48's OS default is Chrome OS, so if I need install Ubuntu in it. I need to follow the procedure of the web-site below.

http://chromeos-cr48.blogspot.com/2011/04/ubuntu-1104-for-cr-48-is-ready.html

Comment: Ah. Published the latest version. But would you mind tell me how to install it or provide some links for my reference?

Comment: I did not know that. According to that blogpost, the machine has its own kernel with modifications needed for the machine to work. I can't help you further at this point.

Answer (score 0):

You can install any kernel you want and use any of them while booting. There is no problem on using one or multiple Kernels at a time. But sometime you should consider the Kernel Mapping to your Ubuntu Version. For example following link lists out the mapping of different kernel to different version of OS. Search for your Ubuntu Version and look on the table which lists the maximum version of kernel you can install and use without any problem:

[Ubuntu to Mainline kernel version mapping](http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/info/kernel-version-map.html)

You can get a complete information of Kernel installing/removing from following link.

[Kernel Mainline Builds](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds)

It helped me a lot to install a new kernel in Ubuntu 12.04.2. Now I can chose any kernel 3.5.0 or 3.8.0 from grub menu.

Following link illustrates how Ubuntu 12.04 LTS works actually. It illustates in very nice way, you would also like:

[Ubuntu LTS Enablement Stack](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack?action=fullsearch&context=180&value=How+to+upgrade+to+ubuntu+12.04.3&titlesearch=Titles)

Hope this short description helps you.